# how to show or hide a group of divs on click of a button (raphael.js)

Tags: jquery, raphael

I am trying to hide or show a group of shapes on click of a shape using JQuery.

Here is what I wrote. Can someone help me correct this code:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
if ($("#parent1, #parent2, #parent3, #parent4").is(":visible")){
    $("#parent1, #parent2, #parent3, #parent4").hide();
}
else
$("#parent1, #parent2, #parent3, #parent4").show();
});
```

Is there a way to use JQuery toggle in Raphael JS?

Comment: Not afaik like that. You could write a custom function to do whatever you need though.

Answer (score 1):

Click the button below.  It wasn't clear from your question if you wanted this to respond to clicking on a shape or on the button, so I attached the handler to both.

The "shape" here is just div with some text in it for the purposes of this sample code - you could do this on shapes too in Raphael.  See here for some pointers on attaching event handlers: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.click

```js
$(function() {
  $('button, .the-divs').click(function(){
    if ($("#parent1, #parent2, #parent3, #parent4").filter(":visible").length) {
      $("#parent1, #parent2, #parent3, #parent4").hide();
    }
    else {
      $("#parent1, #parent2, #parent3, #parent4").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="the-divs" id="parent1">one</div>
<div class="the-divs" id="parent2">two</div>
<div class="the-divs" id="parent3">three</div>
<div class="the-divs" id="parent4">four</div>

<button>click me</button>
```

Comment: Hi Manishie, thanks a lot for taking the trouble. This is what I wanted. I used JQuery toggle to do the trick. It works now. Thanks manishie. Appreciate it.

Comment: if the answer solved your problem, would you accept the answer?